# Accessing Key name of turn.intents in Composer

Tags: botframework

For the sake of this discussion, let's say I need to echo back the name of the intent that was recognized without having a trigger for every intent.

The system returns turn.recognized.intents which is

```
{
“Inmate”: {
"score": 0.433454782
}
```

There are various things listed in the documentation (memory-model-overview), none of which I've been able to get to work.

turn.recognized.score returns the value of score (0.433454782).

turn.recognized.intentName (as described in the doc) returns null.

How do I get the name "Inmate" back?

To test this out, I created a simple EchoBot which uses LUIS and has two intents: none & greeting. I create a trigger for the greeting intent which echos back @{turn.activity.text}. It also echoes back @{turn.recognized.score}. The following  return as null or rather "object reference not set to an instance of an object"

- turn.recognized.intents.intentName
- turn.recognized.intents
- turn.recognized

Comment: Have you tried using turn.recognized.intents.intentName and see if it works?

Comment: Yes, I've tried turn.recognized.intents.intentName and it returns "is evaluated to null". For clarity, I'll add some addition description of where I am looking at this variable above.

Comment: I'll admit I'm struggling with their data handling. Why is "turn.recognized.score" valid and returns a value but "turn.recognized" is null as opposed to an object of some type (which I assumed was json).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the structure is actually:

turn.recognized.intent not "intents" as described in the documentation.

Or rather, the documentation is not fully descriptive. The turn.recognized object is:

```
{
“text”: “hello”,
“alteredText”: null,
“intent”: “Greeting”,
“score”: 0.960900247,
“intents”: {
"Greeting": {
  "score": 0.960900247
}
},
“entities”: {
"$instance": {}
}
```

and this does contain "intents" as well as "intent". I think that the reference in the documentation to "IntentName" was meant to be descriptive rather than literal. There is no property "IntentName" but I'm guessing it was referring to the intent name (in this case) "Greeting" in the structure.

Comment: I agree the documentation might be confusing.You should have added this JSON to your question for more clarity. Glad you could resolve this. You can refer to [this](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues) repo for further issues and doubts regarding the composer in the future.

Comment: It took me a while to figure out how to access the json from the objects from within Composer. It's confusing because the system comes back and says that the objects are null or that it's not set to an instance of the object. I have bf v4 bots in Azure and was able to access the structure of the turn object through that. There is probably(?) a simple way to get the objects to dump their json in Composer but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: you can accept the answer so that it helps others as well.